# Alexa Skill save Start Time

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am building a very simple skill, and the next step is to save currect date time in a slot/variable, to recall it at the end of the skill.

1. open skill, Alexa: "Welcome?"
2. user "Start"
3. save date time of the start moment

Here is the code. Alexa replies "You just triggered startTIME"
How to save in the same time the time? Where will I find the value for a later use?

```
const PlayGameHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'startTIME';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Test Reply!';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the start time in session attributes. Example code:

```
const PlayGameHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'startTIME';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Test Reply!';

    const sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    sessionAttributes.startTimeString = new Date().toISOString();

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

Then later on whenever you want to access that start time:

```
const { startTimeString } = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
const startTime = new Date(startTimeString);
```

Anything you store in session attributes will be available to your skill for the duration of that user's session. If you want to store data for users across sessions, see persistent attributes. More on that here: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/manage-attributes.html